# Lock Camera in ipad 2 for landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Respected Sir,
             Here i am using the uiimagepickercontroller to open the camera and taking the picture its ok.But how i need to lock the landscape mode for uiimagepickercontroller.Here i attached the some code of lines

```
    UIImagePickerController *imgPkr = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPkr.delegate = self;
    imgPkr.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imgPkr.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

    imgPkr.cameraOverlayView = anImageView;
    [theApp.TabViewControllerObject presentModalViewController:imgPkr animated:YES];
    [imgPkr release];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not control `UIImagePickerController`.

Use `AVFoundation`, you will have full control on handling the camera

For use of  AVFoundation , look this apple example

[Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)

Answer (score 2):

Subclass UIImagePickerController, and override this method like this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Then, instead of creating a UIImagePickerController, create an object of the class you made (You can name it, for example UILandscapeImagePickerController) and it will support only landscape.

Comment: its not working for me, still its the UIImagepicker controller is tilted in landscape mode